# python setup installing outside of activated virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, debian, setuptools, packaging

I have a setup code in python using setuptools, and I have the python code to install in /usr/share/mypackage (owned by root), but I'm trying to install the package as a non-privileged user. So, I create a virtual environment (with `virtualenv`) in a directory `$ENVDIR` owned by the user. Then, after activating the virtual environment (with `source $ENVDIR/bin/activate`), I run `python /usr/share/mypackage/setup.py install`.

The problem is that running `setup.py install` tries to create a package.egg-info (or something like that) file inside `/usr/share/mypackage`, which obviously triggers a permission denied error unless I run the setup as root, which is not what I need...

So, the question is: **How can I fix this without running setup.py as root?** That is, how can I prevent setup.py from writing to /usr/share/mypackage?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install as a non-priviledged user into `/usr/share` any workaround would violate unix permissions.  To be fair, you should never ever install anything in `/usr/share` by default.  `/usr/share` is the OS/distro territory and shall be not meddled with when installing software by hand, the correct place is `/usr/local/share`.  Reference: [The FHS spec](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html)

Packaged software install itself by default on `/usr/local` but allow for switches to change this path.  People that compile distros change that *prefix* to `/usr`, without the possibility of changing the prefix an OS would never be compiled!  And python and `setuptools` are no different they have such a prefix switch.

In `setuptools` you define directories relative to the [distribution root](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/examples.html).  Using **absolute paths in `setup.py` is plain bad**.  By default the *distribution root* is what is defined by `sys.prefix`.  Moreover setuptools has the `--prefix` switch that changes that value from the command line.  You shall install your package as a non-priviledged user as:

```
setup.py --prefix=~/local
```

Now, a `virtualenv` activate script sets up the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.  Which you can use when inside the `virtualenv`:

```
setup.py --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV
```

(This is what `pip` does)

---

#### Addendum

I am aware that python sets `sys.prefix` to `'/usr'` by default.  Therefore encouraging packages to be installed directly into `/usr`, as opposed to `/usr/local`.  Yet, that still violates the FHS spec, and shall be avoided.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear... The installation directory is **not** /usr/share. At least it is not supposed to be... When running apt-get install of my debian package, I just put the python source files in /usr/share, but the actual `python setup.py install` is run by the daemon user (I create a user and a group just to run the daemon that I install): in the daemon start script, the call is made to `python setup.py install`, which tries to write to /usr/share, even if I put `python setup.py install --prefix=$ENVDIR`...